# Password generator for a brute force application usin Rust or CLI tool

Tags: security, rust, passwords, command-line-interface, brute-force

I'm working on a distributed application to discover passwords using brute force and other techniques.
For the brute force part, I will need a password generator library for Rust or a command line tool. It needs to generate all possibilities using a specific character set, a certain password length, and a range.
It's important to have the option to get just a specific range because I intend to distribute these 'password batches' to different workers running in parallel.

For example, generate a **4-digit alphanumeric password** getting from the **1001th** to the **2000th** password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no library that I know of, probably because it's not too complicated to just do yourself:

```rust
fn nth_password(char_set: &[char], width: u32, n: usize) -> String {
    (0..width).rev().map(|i| {
        let div = n / char_set.len().pow(i);
        let rem = div % char_set.len();

        char_set[rem]
    }).collect()
}

fn main() {
    let char_set: Vec<char> = ['a'..='z', 'A'..='Z', '0'..='9']
        .into_iter()
        .flatten()
        .collect();

    for n in 1001..1021 {
        let pass = nth_password(&char_set, 4, n);
        println!("pass[{n}]: {pass}");
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c7c13b9ec42a5a16e49577ebcf8ede12)

#### Explaining the algorithm

Each character is an order of magnitude. In base ten at a password length of four, you would have the **1000s** place, then the **100s** place, then the **10s** place, and finally the **1s** place.

`(0..width).rev()` iterates through `3, 2, 1, 0`. We can notice that `1000` is 10^3, `100` is 10^2, `10` is 10^1, and `1` is 10^0; each number corresponds to the power of ten of the numeral place.

So the formula for the order of magnitude of place `i` is `10.pow(i)`. If we divide our number `n` by `10.pow(2)`, we get a number that represents how many full **100s** are in the number (integer division will truncate any **10s** or **1s**). For the number `1234 / 10.pow(2)` results in `12`. But we just want that `2`, so we take the remainder with respect to 10: `12 % 10`.

So for base ten, our code would be

```rust
let div = n / 10.pow(i);
let rem = div % 10;
```

We then extrapolate that to a larger symbol set by replacing `10` with `char_set.len()`, resulting in the algorithm above.

Comment: It looks like a base converter. Could you give me a source for me to understand this algorithm better? I didn't understand very well how `n / char_set.len().pow(i)` helps us to convert the base of each digit isolated.

Comment: @JonathanRodriguesCardoso it is indeed a base converter. Edited an explanation into my answer